# Is it possible to only shuffle a few specific stations on Pandora?

Tags: pandora

I have a plethora of different types of stations on my Pandora and wanted to only shuffle a few of them together when I listen. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the web interface you can do this by selecting "`Shuffle`", then underneath select the little arrow in the yellow box next to "`Shuffle All`" (or possible "`Shuffle <genre>`"). Then select "`My Shuffle`".

Once you've done this, all your stations should have a checkbox next to them. Simply check or uncheck the ones you do or don't want as part of your mix.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. On the app, swipe to the left at the "Shuffle" button and a pencil will appear. Click the pencil icon and it will allow you to pick which stations to shuffle.

Answer (score -1):

In the Android app, you can hold-tap a station and choose Add Variety to add another band to it.  You could also rename it after that.